# Outlook Add-ins regex - exclusions

Tags: javascript, regex, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to write an extension, which will highlight some words in email (Contextual Add-in). For example, I need to highlight "under" word, but not "underscore". I tried to use that regex construction - `under(?!score)`, but it didn't work, despite the fact it generally works in regex testers. Do you know how to implement that regex in Office Add-in? Thanks.

**UPD**: I realised, that I didn't provide all necessary data. Code with regex is in manifest.xml of Office Add-in.

Regex part is:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
   <Label resid="contextLabel" />
       <SourceLocation resid="ITermUrl" />
       <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
          <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
          <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="ITerm" RegExValue="under(?!score)" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" IgnoreCase="true" />
       </Rule>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Result is:

[Office add-in work result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoGqq.png)

I don't want to highlight "underscore". Only "under" or "under score".

Comment: Please provide more details, especially about what you mean by "didn't work", and more of your code is if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @RickKirkham . Added more details.

Comment: I have changed your questions title and added outlook-web-addins tag to get the attention of the right people.

Comment: I can reproduce what you are seeing. I will be looking into this in more depth.

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , did you have a time to check that issue? Thanks for answer.

Comment: We investigated this issue and discovered that it is a limitation of the feature that we missed documenting. We have updated our documentation here to clarify this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/limits-for-activation-and-javascript-api-for-outlook-add-ins